# Performance-proof Master-Detail query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Say I have two tables:

```
Master(id,name,otherproperties);
Detail(id,masterid,name,otherproperties);
```

What is the best way for selecting master and its details into one single query, and build up an object in php like:

```
$master = array(
    "id" = query result,
    "name" = query result,
    "details" = query result
);
```

In my case, this is my table definition:

```
create table supplement_groups(
    supplementgroupid bigint not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    vendorid bigint not null, //don't mind this
    primary key (supplementgroupid),
    foreign key (vendorid) references vendor(vendorid)
);

create table supplement(
    supplementid bigint not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    price decimal(18,2) not null,
    supplementgroupid bigint not null,
    deleted boolean not null default false,
    primary key (supplementid),
    foreign key (supplementgroupid) references supplement_groups(supplementgroupid)
);
```

Comment: Is a simple inner join not doing the job for you? That would be the standard approach, I'd have thought. If not, you may need to look at optimising the indexes that are present (and/or your schema re primary keys etc.)

Comment: @MandyShaw please be more specific. Also, why an inner join? Don't mind the indexes.

Comment: please provide your table definitions and I'll do you an example

Comment: @MandyShaw the table above is just a good example.

Comment: I'm sorry but it has to be easier for you to cut and paste CREATE TABLE definitions that already exist than for me to type them in; and you have the right primary keys etc. on them, I would have to guess all that. (If you want to optimise database performance you need to work at database level.)

Comment: @MandyShaw added :)

Comment: What have you tried? Are you struggling with the SQL, or the PHP?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I am just asking for the most efficient method of retrieving master-detail result sets given the above tables

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, we cannot answer your question. The inner join would be select *
from supplement s
inner join supplement_groups sg
on s.supplementgroupid = sg.supplementgroupid

Comment: @NevilleKuyt thanks for pointing out. Could you tell me why is it an inner join and not a right one?

Comment: The right join equivalent of @NevilleKuyt's sql will include masters with no corresponding detail (with the detail columns on the relevant rows set to null), while an inner join will not return such masters at all. You have not made it clear which option you want, so I assumed that an inner join would do, as it is likely to give better performance. I would recommend, if this distinction is new to you, that you read up on SQL (there are many good textbooks out there) since you really need to understand the basics before you start performance tuning.